# Count calendar days within a date interval using lubridate

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have data set of hospital admission and discharge days from which I want to generate an occupied beds count for each calendar day of a period of three years. I am using the tidyverse and lubridate packages.

My approach so far has been to convert the admit/discharge columns into an interval (the data are sensitive so I can't share actual dates):

```
d <- d %>%
  mutate(duration = admit %--% discharge)
```

and then to create a tibble where each row corresponds to the time range, plus a column of zeroes that can be added to in a for loop:

```
t <- 
  tibble(
    days = as.Date(date("2017-01-01"):date("2019-12-31")), 
    count = 0
  )
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to create a for loop that would sum days that fall within each interval. Here is my attempt thus far, which gives me uniform values of 24 throughout:

```
for(i in timeline$days) {
  if (i %within% d$duration)
    timeline$count = timeline$count + 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another method using `tidyverse` functions.

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>%
  mutate(days = map2(admit, discharge, seq, by = "day")) %>%
  unnest(days) %>%
  count(days) %>%
  right_join(t, by = "days") %>%
  mutate(n = coalesce(n, as.integer(count))) %>%
  select(-count)
```

We create a sequennce of dates between `admit` and `discharge`, `count` every unique date, join it with `t` so that all the dates in `t` remain intact.

Comment: Brilliant. This worked really well too and I like that it worked in the tidyverse!

Comment: Any idea whiy this would throw an error `Caused by error in `seq.int()`:
! 'to' must be a finite number` - I have NAs in my discharge date.

Answer (score 3):

Sample data.

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
d <- tibble(admit = Sys.Date() - sample(300, size = 1000, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(discharge = admit + sample(0:30, size = 1000, replace = TRUE))
d
# # A tibble: 1,000 x 2
#    admit      discharge 
#    <date>     <date>    
#  1 2019-06-18 2019-07-14
#  2 2019-06-11 2019-06-12
#  3 2019-12-24 2020-01-18
#  4 2019-07-13 2019-07-29
#  5 2019-09-08 2019-09-23
#  6 2019-10-15 2019-10-15
#  7 2019-08-11 2019-08-28
#  8 2020-02-07 2020-02-29
#  9 2019-09-03 2019-09-10
# 10 2019-08-20 2019-09-14
# # ... with 990 more rows
```

We can produce a list of date ranges/sequences with `Map` (or `purrr::pmap`):

```r
Map(seq.Date, d$admit, d$discharge, list(by = "days"))[1:2]
# [[1]]
#  [1] "2019-06-18" "2019-06-19" "2019-06-20" "2019-06-21" "2019-06-22" "2019-06-23" "2019-06-24"
#  [8] "2019-06-25" "2019-06-26" "2019-06-27" "2019-06-28" "2019-06-29" "2019-06-30" "2019-07-01"
# [15] "2019-07-02" "2019-07-03" "2019-07-04" "2019-07-05" "2019-07-06" "2019-07-07" "2019-07-08"
# [22] "2019-07-09" "2019-07-10" "2019-07-11" "2019-07-12" "2019-07-13" "2019-07-14"
# [[2]]
# [1] "2019-06-11" "2019-06-12"
```

and then combine these, tabulate them (with `table`), and `enframe` them:

```r
Map(seq.Date, d$admit, d$discharge, list(by = "days")) %>%
  do.call(c, .) %>%
  table() %>%
  tibble::enframe(name = "date", value = "count") %>%
  # because `table` preserves a *character* representation of the Date
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  arrange(date)
# # A tibble: 328 x 2
#    date       count  
#    <date>     <table>
#  1 2019-05-24  1     
#  2 2019-05-25  3     
#  3 2019-05-26  7     
#  4 2019-05-27  8     
#  5 2019-05-28  9     
#  6 2019-05-29 14     
#  7 2019-05-30 20     
#  8 2019-05-31 20     
#  9 2019-06-01 20     
# 10 2019-06-02 21     
# # ... with 318 more rows
```

Comment: That was perfect. Thanks for the quick response and example code to make sample data.

Comment: I should note that this does not necessarily contain all dates in the sequences ... while unlikely, if a date has zero occupancy then it will not be in this final frame. That can be remedied by saving the original `Map(...)` results and re-joining that data back into the overall results (with `count=0`). But again, perhaps unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for the note. For my purposes that should be fine since I'm aggregating by month, so a missing day or two won't matter and there are 1600 patient cases, so should have plenty of coverage.